# facebook graph api don´t publish to news feed

Tags: php, facebook

im trying to update my news feed on facebook. Im using the new graph api. I can connect to graph, but when i try to publish some content to the feed object, nothing happens.

here´s my code:

```
<?php   
$token = "xxxx";

$fields = "message=test&access_token=$token";

$c = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed");
curl_setopt($c,"CURLOPT_POST", true);
curl_setopt($c,"CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS",$fields);

$r = curl_exec($c);
print_r($r);
```

this returns:

```
{"error":{"type":"QueryParseException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}1
```

then I try to pass access_token via GET:

```
$c = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=$token");
```

this returns:

```
{"data":[]}1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks

Comment: A little late here, but could you possibly try to clarify that for me ?

Im having the same problems, and now i got it to return:

{"data":[]}1


So what exactly did you do to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: I put curl options as string... the correct values of curl options is constants... Instead of curl_setopt($c,"CURLOPT_POST", true); you should do curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error!
I was putting CURL options as a string rather than constants.
oopps...